# Ruby On Rails 5, activerecord query where model association ids includes ALL ids in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Has many belongs to association for Recipes and Ingredients.

I am trying to return recipes which have all the ingredient ids in a given array of integers. 
Eg. I search using multiple ingredients, and I want to return any Recipe that has all the ingredients. If too many ingredients are given, but the Recipe includes them all, it should also return the recipe.

I have tried a few things,

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients).where(ingredients: { id: ids })
```

which returns the Recipes that have ANY of the ingredients

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients).where('ingredients.id LIKE ALL ( array[?])', ids)
```

This gives an error: `ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer`

How can I find only the recipes that include all of the ids given in the array?

Comment: Did not test this: `Recipe.joins(:ingredients).where(ingredients: { id: ids }).group_by('recipes.id').having('COUNT(*) = ?', ids.size)`. I will create an answer if it works :)

Comment: Hi, this gives an error ·wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)· Also this won't work for my intended purpose (I'll make the question more clear). If the search array has more ingredients than the Recipe, it should also return the recipe, but if one ingredient is missing, it shouldn't.

Comment: `Recipe.joins(:ingredients).where(ingredients: { id: ids }).group_by('recipes.id').having("COUNT(*) = #{ids.size}")` ?

Comment: Same error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
# Ingredient ID array
ingredient_ids = [....]

Recipe.joins(:ingredients).where(ingredients: { id: ingredient_ids }).
  group("recipes.id").
  having('count(recipes.id) >= ?', ingredient_ids.size)
```

1. First line ensure that only recipes having any of the ingredients are fetched
2. Second & third lines ensure that loaded recipes have minimum ingredient size of the id array, so that if any of the ingredient is missing it won't be considered.

Hope it helps!